# Fetch internal data

Tags: strapi

I'm new to Strapi and I'm trying to build an app. I'm using a single type ('global-settings') to store various data (e.g. field : 'apiUrl') that I'm planning to use internally, in a plugin.

I didn't manage to figure out how I retrieve that data and use it within the plugin.

Can you please help me or indicate where I could find this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandru-gorgos, this will be the best way, you can use it on any controller, service, cronjob, etc.

On my example, (line 6) I am using `strapi.services` to reach for `app-settings` and do a lookup into that single-type model.

On the controller I am using sanitizer to clean the response, you don't really need that if you are not returning that data. You can use only the entity to work with your data.

Using that you will have access to find(), update() and delete for sigle-types

```
'use strict';
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');
module.exports = {
  index: async (ctx, next) => {
    const entity = await strapi.services['app-settings'].find();
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models['app-settings'] });
  },
};
```

[image]

Ref:

1. [backend-customization single-type](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#single-type)

Comment: Note: I am using indexer access to get to the appropriate table, it works better.

Comment: Hi @Pablo... Thank you very much for the response! What I don't understand is where do I write that controller? In the plugin, or in the 'app-settings' api controller? Also, how do I call that data internally? You are retrieving data externally, I need it internally, to store it in a const and use it dynamically. Thanks!

Comment: @alexandru-gorgos tell me exactly what are you doing. Because this code can be used on Controllers & services inside the API folder, and it can be also used on cronjobs if needed. Are you looking  to do a custom endpoint?